# Derivative of a matrix AXBX

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have to find the derivative of a following matrix AXBX, like $$\frac{d(AXBX)}{d(X)}$$ by using matrix differentsation properties where A and B are constant matrices. But I have no idea where to start. Thnx for any help.

Comment: Start by defining the domain.

Comment: It must be $X$ :-)

Comment: @Arthur: One can formulate calculus in terms of dependent variables rather than functions. Arguably, notations like $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ are *supposed* to be interpreted as such. (with typical types for the variables, $f$ is a function, $f(x)$ is not). But that aside, [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) is its own thing.

Comment: @Hurkyl When I made my comment, the question just asked about the derivative of the matrix $AXBX$, and I can immediately think of two different functions that that would represent. Either $X\mapsto AXBX$ (and who said $X$ was the free variable here, really?), or the linear map between two linear spaces given by the matrix $AXBX$ (possibly parametrised by $X$, or any of the others). And there may be other functions that I haven't thought of. Now, after the edit, it is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(X) = AXBX$.

$f(X+H)-f(X) = A (X+H)B(X+H) - AXBX = AXBH + AHBX + AHBH$, so we see that
$Df(X)(H) = AXBH + AHBX$.

(Since $\|f(X+H)-f(X) - (AXBH + AHBX)\| \le K \|H\|^2$ for some $K$.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(X)=AXBX$ and consider $f(X+H)$.
We have

$$f(X+H)=A(X+H)B(X+H) = AXBX + AHBX + AXBH + AHBH.$$

In other words, we have

$$f(X+H) = f(X) + \big(AHBX + AXBH\big) + AHBH$$

Show that $Df_X: H\mapsto AHBX + AXBH\,$ is linear, and that $T: H\mapsto AHBH\,$ satisfies

$$\lim_{H\to 0} \,\frac{\lVert T(H)\rVert}{\lVert H\rVert} = 0.$$

Can you see how this solves our problem?

*$($Hint for the limit: consider using a submultiplicative norm, that is, one that satisfies $\lVert AB\rVert \leq$ $\lVert A\rVert \,\lVert B\rVert$. Examples include the Frobenius or operator norms.$)$*